# C# Import from bacpac to Azure and add database to Elastic pool

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I need to create a database in SQL Azure importing schema and data from a BACPAC file.

I use the method ImportBacPac of the DacServices object.
I see that I can specify some options using DacAzureDatabaseSpecification (Edition, Maximum size...)

I wonder if there is a way to connect the database to elastic pool while importing it from bacpac.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing to a database in elastic pool [isn't supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell#limitations). You can import data into a single database and then [move the database to an elastic pool](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool-manage-csharp.md#move-a-database-into-an-elastic-pool).

Once you have it in same Logical Server. [Move the DB under Elastic Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&tabs=sqlpool#b-moving-a-database-to-a-different-elastic-pool). You can do this in [C#](https://github.com/azure-samples/sql-database-dotnet-manage-sql-dbs-in-elastic-pool/tree/master/#:%7E:text=Create%20another%20database,elastic%20pool%20update.), the [Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-overview#creating-a-new-sql-database-elastic-pool-using-the-azure-portal), Using PowerShell, or using simple query as below:

```
 ALTER DATABASE Your_DB_Name
     MODIFY ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL ( name = Your_Pool_Name) ) ;
```

**Note:** You can create multiple pools on a server, but you can't add databases from different servers into the same pool.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]