# elastic query for update and insert

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

Source: SQL Server 2008 R2
Destination: Azure SQL Database in an elastic pool

I am migrating multiple databases from source to destination using offline DMS. While migrating these databases some stored procedures are giving errors because of three-part and four-part entries in the stored procedure. for this, I am using external tables to convert it into two-part. but some stored procedures are used for DML commands like insert and update. I want to know how I can convert this DML commands stored procedure in elastic query.

Comment: See [sp_execute _remote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-remote-azure-sql-database) for invoking a stored procedure on external tables

Answer (score 0):

As a limitation mentioned in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell#:%7E:text=OperationId%20%24Operation.OperationId-,Limitations,-Importing%20to%20a), Migrating to a DB in elastic pool directly isn't supported. But you can import data into a single database and then [move the database to an elastic pool](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool-manage-csharp.md#move-a-database-into-an-elastic-pool). Once you have it in same Logical Server. [Move the DB under Elastic Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&tabs=sqlpool#b-moving-a-database-to-a-different-elastic-pool).

Refer [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69217729/15969417) ask here or the official MS doc to do this using the [Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-overview#creating-a-new-sql-database-elastic-pool-using-the-azure-portal)

Instead you can also initiate replication from a snapshot or through BULK Load.