# Import a .Bacpac file and move database to an Azure Elastic Pool

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm looking to import a `.bacpac` file in Azure Storage into the SQL Server. Below is the code I have so far using the Azure SDK for .NET. I also want the restored database to be placed in an Elastic Pool automatically.

Apparently, importing directly into an Elastic Pool is not supported: [C# Import from bacpac to Azure and add database to Elastic pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206828/c-sharp-import-from-bacpac-to-azure-and-add-database-to-elastic-pool)

But is there a way to move the imported database into the elastic pool using the new Azure SDK for .NET?

Any help is appreciated.

```
    public static void RestoreToElasticPool(string sourceDbName, string bacpacFileName)
    {
        string backupName = sourceDbName + "/dbbackups/" + bacpacFileName;

        Azure.ResourceManager.ArmClient armClient = new(new DefaultAzureCredential());
        Azure.Core.ResourceIdentifier sqlResourceGroupIdentifier = SqlServerResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(_ResourceGroupSubscriptionId,
                _ResourceGroupName, _SqlServerName);
        Azure.ResourceManager.Sql.SqlServerResource sqlServerResource = armClient.GetSqlServerResource(sqlResourceGroupIdentifier);

        BlobServiceClient bSvcCl = GetStorageAccount(_StorageConnectionString);
        BlobContainerClient contCl = bSvcCl.GetBlobContainerClient(_ActiveProjectsContainer);
        BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = contCl.GetBlockBlobClient(backupName);

        Azure.ResourceManager.Storage.Models.StorageAccountKey storageAccountKey = GetStorageAccountKey(armClient);
        StorageKeyType storageKeyType = new();

        Azure.ResourceManager.Sql.Models.DatabaseImportDefinition databaseImportDefinition = new(storageKeyType, storageAccountKey.Value, blockBlobClient.Uri,
            _SqlUserName, _SqlSvrPwd);

        sqlServerResource.ImportDatabase(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, databaseImportDefinition);
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve it only using sdk .NET? @E. A. Bagby

Comment: @Jahnavi I was, but only hit a dead end. So, I'm using a combination of SQL and the SDK.